# Setting up bash_profile but alias not found?

Tags: macos, terminal, alias

Trying to set up my bash_profile but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
```

And...

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

Save and close the .bash_profile. 
Then close and re-open Terminal and I get this:

```
Last login: Sat Dec 12 12:52:20 on ttys000
-bash: alias: /Users/BilboBaggins/bash_profile’: not found
```

What am I doing wrong? The contents of my .bash_profile looks as follows:

```
alias bp='open ~/.bash_profile'
```

Comment: Which app opens after entering `open ~/.bash_profile` in Terminal?

Comment: I use `.profile` instead of `.bash_profile` however I followed your steps and it works fine on my system.  BTW the `.bash_profile` file opened in TextEdit for me to add `alias bp='open ~/.bash_profile'` and it too is the only line in the target file.  Are you sure Terminal was completely closed after the saved edit and then reopened?

Comment: The error line looks odd it does not have the `.` in it 2) there is a ` in it - have you copied the correct error?

Comment: Try `open $HOME/.bash_profile` for alias.

Comment: @klanomath TextEdit

Comment: @user3439894 I tried typing it in by hand it didn't work. I tried again this time i copy and pasted your exact text from Safari then it worked. I deleted the bash profile and tried it again, it turns out, the magic trick was pasting it from Safari. So weird.  Thank you though

Comment: @Mark I got it to work but it only worked after I copy and pasted text from Safari into TextEdit. It's so weird.

Comment: @user14492 I got the same result but it works now. If i type it in by hand, it doesn't work I have to paste text from Safari for it to work.

Comment: @Hovanky, I copied and pasted both the commands and alias from your question, didn't manually type anything. So if what you posted for the alias came from the original `.bash_profile` file it should have worked for you too. So unless you know exactly what you did/didn't do you might not figure out what went wrong, however since it's working for you now it really doesn't matter. That said, as Mark mentioned, the error message doesn't have the dot in the name so I suspect that's where the error was.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319631/bash-profile-aliases-command-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

I copy and pasted code again from Safari into TextEdit and it worked.

```
 alias bp='open ~/.bash_profile'
```

I deleted my profile, re-started Terminal, and re-did it by hand, and it broke again. It only works when I paste the code from Safari. So weird. No idea why this is.

If anyone has any idea, let me know because i'm so confused.